# Removing values in a character before / in data.table and placing those in a different column

Tags: r, data.table, gsub

I have a data.table dt

```
> dt <- data.table(ch = c("573427/02", "01/17", "030845/84", "15/03", "01", "02", "03", "56/03"), seq = c("23", "32456", "13", "657489", "879605", "564734", "657432", "657431"))
> dt
          ch    seq
1: 573427/02     23
2:     01/17  32456
3: 30845/84     13
4:     15/03 657489
5:        01 879605
6:        02 564734
7:        03 657432
8:     56/03 657431
```

I want to clean the `ch` and the `seq` columns in the data.

1) I want to remove the / and the values before in `ch` and want to keep only characters after the /.

2) in case there are no / present then it should remain as it is(records 5, 6,7 
 must not be changed).

3) if the number of character present before / in `ch` is 5 or 6, then put that value in `seq`.

My result must look like.

```
> dt
              ch    seq
    1:        02 573427
    2:        17  32456
    3:        84  30845
    4:        03 657489
    5:        01 879605
    6:        02 564734
    7:        03 657432
    8:        03 657431
```

How can I do this in data.table in R

Comment: @Jaap, this is not addressing the 3rd condition. where I want to replace the seq value if the value present before / is either 5 or 6 character in length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
dt[grepl('/',ch) & nchar(sub('/.*','',ch)) %in% 5:6, seq := sub('/.*','',ch)
   ][, ch := sub('.*/','',ch)][]
```

gives:

> ```
>    ch    seq
> 1: 02 573427
> 2: 17  32456
> 3: 84 030845
> 4: 03 657489
> 5: 01 879605
> 6: 02 564734
> 7: 03 657432
> 8: 03 657431
> ```